# ¿por qué me marca error al querer compilar mi programa?

Tags: java

Hacer un programa el cual al Ingresar un numero por teclado  este me mostrara su tabla de multiplicar. 
Lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora es esto:

```
public class TablaMultiplicar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        System.out.print("Introduce un número entero: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Tabla del " + n);
        for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++){
             System.out.println(n + " * " + i + " = " + n*i);
        }
    }
}
```

Alguien podría ayudarme en decirme si estoy bien o de lo contrario decirme en donde esta mi error.

Comment: Cual es el problema, compile  tu código y si veo la tabla de multiplicar.

Comment: Que error te marca? Podría ser interesante saber...

Comment: Tan solo te mostraría error si colocas un numero decimal o tipo float en java. de allí funciona muy bien el código que muestras.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta importar la clase util donde esta Scanner

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class TablaMultiplicar {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    System.out.print("Introduce un número entero: ");
    n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Tabla del " + n);
    for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++){
         System.out.println(n + " * " + i + " = " + n*i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias a todos.  :)

Comment: Para marcar la solución, esta respuesta apareció primero (unos segundos antes) que la anterior, así que ésta debe ser marcada como solución. ¿Ya sabrás cómo hacerlo @Elizabeth?  Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Hola el único error que vi es que te falta importar la clase Scanner, después de eso funciona correctamente ya lo probé

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Al declarar

```
Int n = 0;
```

Tienes que asignarle valor a tu variable

Comment: No es necesario añadir valor a una variable, puedes iniciarla cuando quieras.